# Java ElasticSearch : Getting empty result when calling with different offset in same call

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have service in which I am calling elastic server and whatever response I get, I iterate over it and filter records on depending upon criteria, if after filtering I get records size as same input_size I return the result or else I again call the elastic by changing query and increasing offset. Code is somewhat like below.

```
SearchCriteria {
    private int offset;
    private int limit;
    private Filters filter;
}

ElasticService {
    private ResultObj getDataFromElastic(SearchCriteria criteria){
         List<Document> op = new ArrayList<>();
         do {
             SearchRequest searchReq = buildElasticQuery(criteria, offset, limit);
             Page<Document> res = repository.search(searchReq);
             count = 0;
             for(Document r:res){
                if(r.getStatus() != "Ready"){
                   continue; }
             count +=1;
             op.add(r);
             }
         if(count <= limit){
             offset = offset + 10;
             }
         }while(count <= Limit);

}
}
```

Now the main issue is when I pass offset as 0 and limit as 10 it goes for 2nd elastic call because count didn't match the limit. But elastic returns **empty response for 2nd call.**

```
2022-11-21 17:59:05.130  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Search Service :-- Offset and limit for this call 0 , 10
2022-11-21 17:59:05.131  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Query - Pagegable : Page request [number: 1, size 10, sort: Id.keyword: ASC, NULLS_FIRST]
2022-11-21 17:59:18.634  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Search Service :-- Result size is 3
2022-11-21 17:59:05.130  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Search Service :-- Offset and limit for this call 10 , 10
2022-11-21 17:59:05.131  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Query - Pagegable : **Page request [number: 1, size 10, sort: Id.keyword: ASC, NULLS_FIRST]**
2022-11-21 17:59:18.634  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Search Service :-- Result size is 0
```

but I send seperate request with offset as 10 and limit 10, elastic returns data with some size.

```
2022-11-21 17:65:05.130  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Search Service :-- Offset and limit for this call 10 , 10
2022-11-21 17:65:05.131  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Query - Pagegable : **Page request [number: 1, size 10, sort: Id.keyword: ASC, NULLS_FIRST]**
2022-11-21 17:65:18.634  INFO 11951 ---ElasticService    : Search Service :-- Result size is 3
```

I tried changing the way I am calling elastic client from repository class that extends `ElasticsearchRepository` to using high level Rest client `RestHighLevelClient` .

```
resultList = leadIndexRepository.search(searchQuery);
```

```
searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I also tried by changing the how we use the Pagination thing. First I tried with

```
return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(baseQueryBuilder)
                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit, buildSort(criteria)))
                .build();
```

then I removed the withPageable from here and added

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = buildSearchQuery(criteria, limit, pageNumber);
SearchSourceBuilder source = new SearchSourceBuilder()
         .query(searchQuery.getQuery()).from(offset).size(limit);
SearchRequest searchRequest=new SearchRequest(leadDocumentProperties.getName()).source(source);
```

I also tried few others way but none of it worked.